# Relation between power dissipation and imag part of susceptibility

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions, dissipation, fluctuation-dissipation

I am trying to understand the following relation between power dissipation and the imaginary part of the susceptibility, from Sethna's Statistical Mechanics textbook. Why does the integral equal the imaginary part of the susceptibility? Also, when doing integration, why can we assume that the bounds are symmetric? Explicit math steps would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I can not open the image link, maybe you could write it down explicitly. This may also help: [How imaginary part of susceptibility is measure of dissipation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/495687/how-imaginary-part-of-susceptibility-is-measure-of-dissipation)

Comment: That question doesn't walk through all the math showing how the dissipated power is related to the imag part of susceptibility, so I was still confused

Comment: How about this one? [Fluctuation-dissipation theorem and Kramers-Kronig relations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/244643/226902)